# Remote commands on Windows Server 2003 Standard

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I was wondering if there was any method of connecting to a windows 2003 server using Powershell to have it return any data from the server, such as operating system, processes etc. I've gotten different commands to get data to return from 2008-2016 but can't seem to get 2003 server to respond to any commands and return any data.

Comment: Please show us the code you have already tried and tell us what is not working

Comment: 2003 server can support PowerShell 1.0 and doesn't have PowerShell remoting capability. You could try using `psexec` there.

Comment: I've tried WMI-object, invoking commands and trying to open a PSSession (got no experience working on 2k3 servers at all)

Comment: Server 2003 can run up to PowerShell v2. However, support for Server 2003 ended 4 years ago, so it shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: We're still using W2k3 as well.  I either interrogate AD, use Get-WmiObject or use Invoke-Command with "psexec".

Comment: @MichelBalencourt, would you be able to share the code here for example?